# How to do carrier aggregation?

Tags: matlab, lte

I have generated 20 MHz bandwidth LTE waveform. I wanted to do carrier aggregation of this signal to get 100 MHz Signal.

I want to understand how carrier aggregation is done mathematically, so using built-in matlab functions isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: sounds like a programming problem if you don't *want* to use what's there (without giving a reason) instead of a signal processing problem. That would be off-topic. But it *could* be on-topic if you explain **why** you *need* to implement this on your own.

Comment: I want to know how it could be done mathematically.

Comment: I've edited your question to reflect that. However, that is not done on the waveform of a single carrier. So I'm still not sure what you're asking for. You can't "aggregate" a single 20 MHz wide signal.

Comment: In LTE, the main benefit of Carrier Aggregation is to assemble fragmented frequency bands hence the aggregation is designed at *protocol level*. This means that each carrier is implemented as it has always be and the control channel (eg pdcch of pcell) will tell the receiver how to extract the data from secondary carriers. No math involves here except 5x20MHz = 100MHz to indicate how much bandwidth we are using.

Comment: example of CA using matlab LTE System Toolbox https://fr.mathworks.com/help/lte/examples/release-12-downlink-carrier-aggregation-waveform-generation-demodulation-and-analysis.html